# Problem with LiveData response from retrofit request

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-livedata

Can someone explain me why my MutableLiveData is always "null" ?
In another project I didnt this same like here and it working. Maybe I'm blind or something and I cannot see easy errors or something.

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun setString(word: String) {
        mutableLiveData.value = word
    }

    fun getString(): LiveData<String> {
        return mutableLiveData
    }
}
```

---

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)

        homeViewModel = activity!!.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        }

        homeViewModel.getString().observe(this, Observer<String>{
                t -> textView.text = t
        })

        AsyncTaskAllInvoices(ApiConnection().connectionApiInitialize(), this).execute()
        return root
    }
}

class AsyncTaskAllInvoices(val apiService: ApiService, val activity: HomeFragment) : AsyncTask<Any, Any, Any>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?) {
        ApiConnection().showAllInvoices(apiService, activity)
    }
}
```

---

```
class ApiConnection: Fragment()  {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

    fun connectionApiInitialize(): ApiService {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(LocalVariables.baseApiURl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }


    fun showAllInvoices(apiService: ApiService, activity: Fragment)  {
        homeViewModel = activity!!.run {
            ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        }
        val call = apiService.getAllInvoices()
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<List<InvoiceResponse>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<InvoiceResponse>>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.v("parser", "call onFailure")
            }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<InvoiceResponse>>?, response: Response<List<InvoiceResponse>>?) {
                if (response != null) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        homeViewModel.setString(response!!.body()!![0].driver)                    
                        Log.v("parser", homeViewModel.getString().value)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When I'm using:

```
Log.v("parser", homeViewModel.getString().value)
```

in onResponse im getting value which should be, but it isnt updated in my FragmentActivity. Any ideas?

THanks :_)

Comment: maybe onResponse does not happen in the main thread??? try using postValue(word) instead of value=workd

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: then the only other answer I can come up with is that your provider created different viewmodels , try replacing ViewModelProviders.of(this) with ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!) and make sure that both fragments are attached to the same activity

Comment: actually a better solution may be to replace `ApiConnection().showAllInvoices(apiService, activity)` with `ApiConnection().showAllInvoices(apiService, homeViewModel)` to make sure that the response goes directly to the viewmodel, I don't see a reason why the client should have a reference to the fragment (which may have been destroyed when it finishes)